# c# Get fallback font

Tags: c#, winforms

In my app. , users can select the font used to display text in a RichTextBox. I measure each line to draw a background color for each or them. This measurement depends on the text font. The problem occurs if the RichTextBox Font can not display the text so it uses a fallback font. For example,  the font "Simplified Arabic" can display Arabic chars but not English chars, so another English font is used, while RichTextBox Font and SelectionFont properties still returning the "Simplified Arabic" font!. Same problem occurs if the displayed text is Arabic while RichTextBox font doesn't support Arabic chars. How can I get the actual font used to display the text? Or how can I know if a font supports specific language or not, so I can use alternative one if the font can't display the text?

Comment: That feature does not exist, but you only need the measurement to be accurate.  Winforms provides *two* ways to measure text, Graphics.MeasureString and TextRenderer.MeasureText.  We can't see what you use and you have not provided any repro code that we can try ourselves to propose a solution.  But one of them is not correct, RTB uses the latter.  If that doesn't help then consider using a font that does not require fallback.

Comment: Users can choose the font, and I cant know if it can display the text or not (I even do not kow the languade of the text!. This is a subtitle editor and the user is free to use any subtitle from any language. I only test with English and Arabic.

Comment: I used a workarroung. I let the user choose two fonts, one for English subtiles, and the other for Arabic ones. I check if the text contains Arabic chars to set the correct font. This is like MS Word does.